# Outputting values from the INSERT clause if INSERT fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an insert statement like the following;

```
INSERT INTO Table1(Value1, Value2, Value3)
SELECT A.Value1, B.Value2, C.Value3
FROM       Fn1 A 
           INNER JOIN Table2 B ON A.ID = B.AID
           INNER JOIN Table3 C ON C.ID = B.CID
WHERE      A.ID = 4
```

In the above code there is a chance that nothing would actually insert, for example if the JOIN returns no values. Is there a way I could output Value1, Value2 and Value3 even if the insert fails? MERGE and OUTPUT wouldn't in this case as nothing was actually inserted.

Im trying to insert some auditing into a much more complex query with dynamically calculated values without having to re-write it to calculate the values into variables first, so was wondering if there was a shortcut like above.

Comment: Did you consider that if the `JOIN` returns no values, there simply **are no** Value1, Value2 and Value3 to show? Also that is not a "failure" of the `INSERT`, it is an empty result from the `SELECT`.

Comment: If the data doesn't exist, what are you wanting to insert into the table?

Comment: what you would like to insert, if your select query not returning any value ?

Comment: So this is a simplified example - there is data coming from various places with various kinds of joins, most importantly including subqueries. So, for example, Value 1 might exist but Value2 and Value3 might not. I would still want to return Value1.

Comment: @RyanHargreaves don't use inner joins, use left joins

Comment: I've realised i've phrased my question badly, and you guys made a good point - I realised that I am trying to do something a bit stupid here - apologies for the time wasting!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO Table1(Value1, Value2, Value3)
SELECT A.Value1, B.Value2, C.Value3
FROM       Fn1 A 
           FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 B ON A.ID = B.AID
           FULL OUTER JOIN Table3 C ON C.ID = B.CID
WHERE      A.ID = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 INSERT INTO Table1(Value1, Value2, Value3)
    SELECT A.Value1, ISNULL(B.Value2,0), ISNULL(C.Value3,0)
    FROM       Fn1 A 
               LEFT JOIN Table2 B ON A.ID = B.AID
               LEFT JOIN Table3 C ON C.ID = B.CID
    WHERE      A.ID = 4
```